# How to unit test rxjs shareReplay?

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I am trying to test the following scenario for a service using RxJS's [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) method which caches the response so that subsequent subscriptions do not need to make another call:

```
it('should only make 1 http call for multiple subscriptions', () => {

  myService.doSomeAsyncOperation('ABCD').subscribe();
  myService.doSomeAsyncOperation('EFGH').subscribe();
  myService.doSomeAsyncOperation('IJKL').subscribe();

  // Expectation?

});
```

It would seem that exposing some form of observable state is necessary to test this properly, e.g. `.getCallsMade()` which could be used to say:

```
expect(myService.doSomeAsyncOperation('IJKL').subscribe().getHttpCallsMade() < 2).toBeTruthy()
```

I could add a counter and try to do this manually, but this doesn't seem optimal as it's quite a bit of state to manage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for the HttpTestingController, see [Testing HTTP requests](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests).  You'd end up with something like `expect(httpTestingController.match(testURL).length).toEqual(1)`

Comment: Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is the answer:

`httpTestingController.expectOne('endpoint-called-from-async-operation');`

https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController#expectone